# How do I make a good multiplication chart

Tags: python, loops, formatting

I am writing a program that is suppose print a number that corresponds to its factor, rows by columns, otherwise known as a multiplication table. The first row and column each start with 0, then go to 10. Each number on each row is multiplied by each number on each column. While my program is successful in generating each number, it is not lined up. The reason for this is because on numbers with more than one digit, take up more space (10 is not lined up with 9 because of space, affecting other numbers lineage).
I having tried many things, one including adding more space to each row and column.

Here is some of my code:

```
t = 1
row = ""

for i in range(11):

    i = str(i)
    row += i
    row += "  "

print(row)

row = ""

for i in range(1, 11):

    row = ""

    for i in range(1, 11):

        i *= t
        i = str(i)
        row += i
        row += "  "

    i = int(i)
    i /= 10
    print("%0.0f" % i, "", row)

    t += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a recent Python (>3.7 I think) you can use the "f-string" to right-align numbers:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    for t in range(1, 11):
       print(f"{i*t:>5}", end="")
    print()
```

which gives

```
 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
 2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18   20
 3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27   30
 4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36   40
 5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50
 6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48   54   60
 7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56   63   70
 8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72   80
 9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72   81   90
10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90  100
```